# originate conference from python esl

Tags: freeswitch, conference

I want to setup a conference call, initiating from  an ESL program.

In my python script I call the first number :

```
freeswitchcon.api("originate","sofia/gateway/MySIP/91XXXXXXXXXX+" &conference(9099)"
```

then I call another number:

```
freeswitchcon.bgapi("originate","sofia/gateway/MySIP/91XXXXXXXXXX+" &conference(radioHealth_${strftime(%Y-%m-%d)}+flags{mute})"
```

My Dialplans are:

```
<extension name="conf_demo">
<condition field="destination_number" expression="^9099$">
<action application="conference" data="radioHealth_${strftime(%Y-%m-%d)}+flags{endconf}"/>
</condition>

<extension name="conf_demo">
<condition field="destination_number" expression="^9098$">
<action application="conference" data="radioHealth_${strftime(%Y-%m-%d)}+flags{mute}"/>
</condition>
```

I get a call on the first number, but not on the second number. Freeswitch logs are:

```
2016-04-18 05:37:26.417807 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1055 New Channel sofia/external/91XXXXXXXXXX [a22ea00c-0527-11e6-86df-415bf8be0d99]
2016-04-18 05:37:26.777867 [NOTICE] sofia.c:7539 Hangup sofia/external/91XXXXXXXXXX [CS_CONSUME_MEDIA] [CALL_REJECTED]
2016-04-18 05:37:26.777867 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1641 Session 24 (sofia/external/91XXXXXXXXXX) Ended
2016-04-18 05:37:26.777867 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1645 Close Channel sofia/external/91XXXXXXXXXX [CS_DESTROY]
```

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a couple of years late, but I noticed that you are calling the normal api in your first originate command:

```
freeswitchcon.api("originate","sofia/gateway/MySIP/91XXXXXXXXXX+" &conference(9099)"
```

This means that the first call will be initiated but then python will wait for that call to return (i.e. when it is hung up) before continuing.

If you use `freeswitchcon.bgapi`, as in your second call, then the call will be originated in the background and python  will not wait for the call to end before continuing.